Chat meeting #2 on tuesday, 24th of january 2012
So I've got myself in gear and organised chat meeting number 2, a chance for as all to get together in chat. I apologise for only giving six days notice. Things I think we should consider covering:

Challenges. I have some work to do this weekend on this - and SE have given us a special dispensation to help make this possible. I'll cover this more in chat.
Quality Reviews. On MSO, there is a discussion currently about how communities can evaluate quality of their content. I think we should think about how we'd evaluate this ourselves and have a look at our own quality. Mostly because I think its excellent and we can say how amazing we are, but y'know... SE are trying to come up with ways to evaluate site quality, in short.
I wonder if it is worth doing some Q&A on close voting? There are currently 16 users who can vote to close a question; we're even starting to see the odd vote here and there but I think we should make sure, especially for users who are new to the engine, that people understand you can moderate crypto too via close voting. I can't work out if its just that I and the other mods check crypto far more regularly or if people are unsure about close votes/generally just nice - so this is something I want to ask . If you want to let me know in the comments feel free. I might even produce a handy guide.
Books. I wonder if we should have an informal "recommend your favourite introductory cryptography book at the end" of the chat?

Any other topics people want to cover? Thoughts on the above? Feel free to reply with anything you want to bring up/ask/cover off in the chat, or tell me any of the above is a stupid idea. Really. It's your chat event.
